# Symfony2 many-to-many does not update inverse side

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the entities: Students and StudyGroups

Everything works fine with Study Groups. I can choose the list of Students belongs to Study Groups, and Doctrine creates the associations.

However when I want to do the same thing from the other side (choose the Study Groups for students), nothing happens.

Here are the important parts of my YAML file configuration

StudyGroups.orm.yml

```
manyToMany:
    students:
        targetEntity: Students
        inversedBy: studyGroups
        cascade: ["persist"]
        joinTable:
            name: students_study_groups
            joinColumns:
                study_groups:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                students:
                    referencedColumnName: id
```

Students.orm.yml

```
manyToMany:
    studyGroups:
        targetEntity: StudyGroups
        mappedBy: students
        cascade: ["persist"]
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

I also tried the following modification in StudyGroups.php entity file

```
public function addStudent(\AppBundle\Entity\Students $students) {
    $students->addStudyGroup($this); // ADDED THIS LINE
    $this->students[] = $students;
    return $this;
}
```

Same in Students.php entity file

```
public function addStudyGroup(\AppBundle\Entity\StudyGroups $studyGroups) {
    $studyGroups->addStudent($this); // ADDED THIS LINE
    $this->studyGroups[] = $studyGroups;
    return $this;
}
```

The interesting thing I found about this problem, is that if I switch the Inverse and Owning side in StudyGroups.orm.yml and Students.orm.yml the issue will switch too.

I am aware that this is mentioned here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html

11.2. Important concepts

*Changes made only to the inverse side of an association are ignored. Make sure to update both sides of a bidirectional association (or at least the owning side, from Doctrine’s point of view)*

This is my problem. My changes to my inverse side are ignored. How can I fix this ? I tried all those things mentioned by other users, but still doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1**

Here is my method for editing **Students**. Please note that if I switch the inverse and owning side (in the YAML file configuration), the Study Groups editing will work, and the Students editing will not work. (by not work, I mean it does not create the association between the two)

```
public function editStudentAction(Request $request, $student) {

    /* DATABASE SERVICE */
    $this->db_helper = $this->get('db.helper');

    /* DOCTRINE */
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $student = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Students')->find($student);

    /* INVALID ID */
    if (count($student) == 0) {
        /* INVALID ID */
        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add(
                'error', 'Invalid ID!'
        );
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('index'));
    }

    /* GET STUDENT FORM */
    $form = $this->newStudentForm($student, "edit");

    /* HANDLE FORM SUBMISSION */
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {

        /* CHECK IF STUDENT ONLY WANT TO ENROLL 2 STUDY GROUPS */
        if (count($student->getStudyGroups()) > 2) {
            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add(
                    'error', 'Students may only enroll 2 study groups at the same time!'
            );
        } else {
            try {

                /* SAVE TO DATABASE */
                $em->persist($student);
                $em->flush();

                /* REDIRECT TO MAIN PAGE */
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('index'));
            } catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $e) {

                /* HANDLE DUPLICATE KEY ISSUE */
                if ($e->getPrevious()->getCode() === '23000') {
                    $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add(
                            'error', 'User already exists!'
                    );
                } else
                    throw $e;
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->render('default/new.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'object' => "student"
    ));
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your controller? I have a feeling I can see what's going on, but would need to see your controller to be sure.

Comment: I added the controller part.

Answer (score 0):

I'm highly surprised this works either side, as it would appear you have a potential infinite loop happening.

addStudent() calls addStudyGroup() which calls addStudent() which calls addStudyGroup() which calls addStudent()............ Remove those two "ADDED THIS LINE", this needs to happen in your controller.

Here's an update to go in your controller. First you need to remember the existing list of study groups for this student before you create the form:

```
    /* GET ORIGNAL COLLECTIONS */
    $originalGroups = new ArrayCollection(); // requires: use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    foreach ($student->getStudyGroups() as $group) {
        $originalGroups->add($group);
    }

    /* GET STUDENT FORM */
```

Now you need to remove any removed study groups from the new collection,

```
    /* MANY TO MANY */
    foreach ($originalGroups as $group) {
        if (!$student->getStudyGroups()->contains($group)) {
            $student->removeStudyGroup($group);
            $group->removeStudent($student);
            $em->remove($group);
        } else {
            $group->addStudent($student);
            $em->persist($group);
        }
    }

    /* SAVE TO DATABASE */
    $em->persist($student);
```

Comment: So the situation is the following. I want to edit a student who has 2 study groups. I remove him from one of the study groups and I get this error:

An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO students_study_groups (study_groups, students) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [1, 98]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '98-1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Did you remove the "// ADDED THIS LINE" lines from your entities yet? That error will occur because of the looping I referred to. This line "$group->addStudent($student);" might also not be required.